# Get process ID based on apppool after a recycle

Tags: powershell, iis, recycle, pid

Our apppools recycle at around 02:00 nightly. I want to create a processdump after the recycle but the process ID changes after a recycle.

How can i get the process ID of the recycled apppool based on the apppool identity (Username running the process) or apppool name?

I tried running:

```
appcmd list wp
```

This gave me the names + id's. How can i filter this result to save only the Id based on a specific name into a variable using powershell?

I was thinking about something like :

```
$processId = appcmd list wp | Where-Object {$_.apppool -eq "MyApp_web"}
```

Thanks in advance,

Tim

> EDIT:
>
> $workerprocess = appcmd list wp /apppool.name:"MyApp_Web"
>
> returns the following: WP "6816" (applicationPool:MyApp_Web)

Now i just want the ID of this proces, not all the other data

> EDIT 2 : Thanks to Vesper
>
> $WebWorker = appcmd list wp /apppool.name:"MyApp_Web"
>
> if ($WebWorker -match "\d+") { $WebId=$matches[0] }
>
> Write-Host

Comment: Why would you want a process dump *after* the recycle? It's a new, freshly spun up process, nothing interesting to find in there

Comment: I'm creating a watcher that goes off when the process hits >90% of the CPU. Apperently the first call after a recycles makes the w3wp.exe process go to 100% cpu. I want a process dump of that

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's by design, see ["Compiling on first request" in this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: You can use /text to return only the id:  `$WebWorker = appcmd list wp /apppool.name:"MyApp_Web" /text:WP.NAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, all you need to do is get the PID out of the string. Since a PID is a sequence of digits, you can use a regex-match to get the matching region, like this:

```
if ($workerprocess -match "\d+") { $pid=$matches[0] }
```

This will return `6816` out of your string.